# pass object from function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm going to be able to retrieve the data by calling getTicket via listTicket

listTicket :

```
listTicket()
   {
     objectTicket = this.getTicket();
     objectTicket.map((userData)=>{
      alert(userData.id)
    })
}
```

getTicket Code:

```
async getTicket () {
      return await fetch('url', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            uid: '1',
            type: '0'
          })
      })
        .then((response) => {return response.json()})
        .then((responseJson) => {
          return responseJson;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          alert(error);
        });
    }
```

I get this error:

> typeerror objectTicket.map is not a function

Comment: In order to use map, objectTicket should be an array. But unfortunately you have object instead of array.

Answer (score 2):

From getTicket method you're getting Promise, so you should to subscribe to it:

```
listTicket() {
     objectTicket = this.getTicket();
     objectTicket.then((res) => { 
       res.map((userData)=> {
          alert(userData.id)
       })
     })
}
```

Comment: thanks, i replaced alert(userData.id) with view but i get error invariant violation, object are not valid, please help

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that `getTicket()` is a function that returns a Promise whereas `map` is defined on arrays.

Answer (score 1):

As `getTicket` is returning a Promise `listTicket` method should be also `async`.

```
async listTicket() {
   objectTicket = await this.getTicket();
   objectTicket.map((userData)=> {
      alert(userData.id)
   });
}
```

Comment: thanks, i replaced alert(userData.id) with view but i get error invariant violation, object are not valid, please help

Comment: I don't get your question. Could you paste your code here or deploy your code somewhere, let say on jsfiddle or some similar site. What is it 'view' ?

Comment: I added a new post. please guide me

Answer (score 0):

An **async** function **returns a promise** and resolves with the return value of the function.

So, when you are calling the listTicket function. the listTicket function is returning the promise Object along with the return value{VIEW} and that is creating the problem.

To solve the problem you should set the **objectTicket** value to a state variable and loop over state variable.